# Change OpenEars pitch dynamically (on the fly)

Tags: ios, openears

I have an iOS app that reads text using the OpenEars API.  I am using the latest version (1.2.5).  I can not figure out how to change the pitch while the words are being read ("on the fly").  I created a slider to control the pitch.  A delegate is fired as the slider is changed.  In the delegate function, the FliteController target_mean is changed.  The intent was to have the pitch change as soon as the target_mean value was changed.  My code is as follows:

```
-(void)sayTheMessage:(NSString *)message {

    // if there is nothing there, don't try to say anything
    if (message == nil)
        return;

    [self.oeeo setDelegate:self];

    // we are going to say what is in the label...
    @try {

        // set the pitch, etc...
        self.flite.target_mean = pitchValue; // Change the pitch
        self.flite.target_stddev = varienceValue; // Change the variance
        self.flite.duration_stretch = speedValue; // Change the speed

        // finally say it!
        [self.flite say:message withVoice:self.slt];

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

        if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(messageError)])
            [delegate messageError];        
    }
    @finally {

    }
}


-(void)changePitch:(float)pitch {

    if ((pitch >= 0) && (pitch <= 2)) {

        // save the new pitch internally
        pitchValue = pitch;

        // change the pitch of the current speaking....
        self.flite.target_mean = pitchValue;
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenEars developer here. You can't change the pitch on the fly with FliteController since the pitch is set before speech is processed.